# Get TextBox values with foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["chestionar"].ConnectionString);
TextBox[] rasp = new TextBox[] { textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, textbox4, textbox5 };

foreach (TextBox raspuns in rasp)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Raspunsuri Values(@raspuns,@cnp,@data,'5')", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", Session["sesiune_cnp"]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raspuns", raspuns.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("User6.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

After I insert in those 5 TextBxes values in the table I only get the value from the first one.  Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: because you're redirecting probably.

Comment: I think Response.Redirect should be after loop

Comment: off topic but not less important: think about a clean abstraction between UI stuff and DB Stuff.

Comment: off topic 2: if your con.Open() wont work, then your con.Close() in your finally block will probably throw another exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `try` you are using `Response.Redirect("User6.aspx");`.

`Response.Redirect` will abort the thread (all code stops executing), which gets call right after the first insertion into the database.

Instead, you want to do the redirect after your `foreach`:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["chestionar"].ConnectionString); 
TextBox[] rasp = new TextBox[] { textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, textbox4, textbox5 }; 

foreach (TextBox raspuns in rasp) 
{ 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Raspunsuri Values(@raspuns,@cnp,@data,'5')", con); 

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", Session["sesiune_cnp"]); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raspuns", raspuns.Text); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()); 

    try 
    { 
        con.Open(); 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 

    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex); 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
        con.Close(); 
    } 
}
Response.Redirect("User6.aspx");
```

One last thing. Your code doesn't appear to be cleaning up resources. You should be putting your SqlCommand and SqlConnection in a `using` statement.